# Javascript: remove an element.cloneNode() from memory

Tags: javascript, clonenode

I am a situation where I have to clone an element, read it's attributes and other parsing functionality, but now since I don't do `element.parentNode.appendChild(clonedElement)` how do I delete this clone from memory?

```
var clonedElement = element.cloneNode();

// do some stuff with it

clonedElement = null; // is this good enough?
```

So yea, is the `clonedElement = null;` good enough to clear it from memory?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remove the variable's reference to the DOM node, use

```
element = null;
```

Since Javascript is garbage collected, you don't need to delete objects themselves 
they will be removed when there is no way to refer to them anymore.

but

If a DOM element which is removed is reference-free 
(no references pointing to it) then yes 
the element itself is picked up by the garbage collector as well as any event 
handlers/listeners associated with it.

if there are references that still point to said element, 
the element and its event listeners are retained in memory.

```
var removeChilds = function (node) 
{
    var last;
    while (last = node.lastChild) node.removeChild(last);
};

removeChilds( element ) ;
element=null;
```